# Joomla getItems running out of memory with big results set

Tags: caching, joomla, custom-component, records, large-data

I've got just over 10,000,000 records in the database of my component and I think getItems/getListQuery is trying to load every single one of them into memory.  The search form on the site extremely slow or comes back saying php is out of memory.

phpMyAdmin seems to be able to handle displaying this data - why not Joomla?

The strange thing is that the items are then displayed correctly using the globally set list limit of 5 to a page.

I've just looked and Joomla's cache is disabled - is that screwing me up here?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have a limit set in your query?

Comment: I think the limit is set by the Global Configuration and it appears to work - things are paginated.

Comment: Actually, I've been looking at `/libraries/legacy/model/list.php` and in `getItems` it seems to use `getListItems` and save the result in `$this->cache[$store]`. Does this mean joomla tries saving all the items from a search result in a cache?

Comment: I tried ditching all but 1 million records and it's still majorly struggling. This is running on a local development machine so it's not a problem with the server.  The database is just 7 fields per row with a primary key (id). I've just decided that Joomla is less than useful for web apps with over 500k plus records.  I've even tried upping the memory limit in php to something ridiculous and it's still painfully slow or timing out.  I'm blowing my brains out trying to integrate this app with Joomla but I'm thinking now that it's just not worth it...

Comment: What version of Joomla are you using?  (We have Joomla extensions deployed that generate on the fly reports from many thousands of form submissions that result in hundreds of thousands of records and haven't seen this problem).

Comment: The list limit is used after you've one the main part of the query to do the pagination, but you wnat to addd a limit earlier.

Comment: I'm using Joomla 3.1 - how would I set the list limit before getItems sends the whole lot to the cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it in the end by copying the getPagination, getTotal, getItems etc. from the library's (list.php) and into my model (to override them). Then in each method, I made sure the results where returned instead of sending them to the cache.

The getTotal function seems to count the number of rows instead of doing a seperate count(*). That's ok with a few thousand records but over 1/2 million is asking for trouble!